How to preserve POST requests when using NGINX redirect
I have an nodejs based application running on port 4700
I have installed and implemented NGINX to add ssl to the server.
In NGINX Config I have added 2 server blocks, the first listens to http requests and forwards them to https
the second server block handles the https requests, and proxies the requests to the app running on port 4700.
Everything works well, except for POST requests to HTTP, these get converted to GET requests.
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

client_body_buffer_size 128k;
client_max_body_size    4096M;  # Adjust based on your requirements
sendfile                on;
tcp_nopush              on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

server {
    listen       80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name  server.name.com;
    
    if ($request_method = POST) {
        return 307 https://$server_name$request_uri$is_args$args;
    }

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             server.name.com;
    ssl_certificate         C:\Path\to\file.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     C:\Path\to\file.pem;
    client_max_body_size    4096M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:4700;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

}
When I tried to use 307 or 308 for the redirect, the request times out and I get " (socket hang up)" error.
Any suggestions on how to redirect POST requests from HTTP to HTTPS successfully using NGINX would be greatly apprecited!

You do not need the $is_args$args as it's already included in the $request_uri string.
